# What to do with new tags that should not be?

Tags: discussion, tags

I visited the [new tags page](https://security.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=new), and realized that there are lots of new tags that might not have a reason to exist or be better of as synonyms to an existing tag. (I could provide examples, but this questions is about the general case and not about specific tags.)

What should I do about new tags that I feel should not be? Is it OK to just remove them from the one question that is tagged with them, thereby leaving them at the mercy of the garbage collector? Should I start a meta question about every single tag I feel is unnecesarry? Or should I just let it be?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If a tag has no categorization usefulness, it should be removed. If a clearly bad tag is used by only one question, you as a 2K+ user can strike it out of existence yourself. (Users without the edit privilege must fix all problems with posts they edit, in addition to removing useless tags. In my opinion, everyone should completely repair all posts they touch, though.)

If a dubious tag is used by more than a few questions, bring it up on meta and wait for community consensus. When demolishing bad tags, be careful to wait a bit between edit bursts so as not to flood the front page with old barely-updated questions.